# Unable to connect to Express welcome page after install

Tags: node.js, express, installation

I am a total newbie and have a problem I just can't find the answer to.  I followed the steps on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/development_environment and I'm not able to connect to the sample pages with express.  The hellonode.js connects fine when I run that.

Both of the express examples connect when I start the server and I get the 'example app listening...' message but when I go to the page in any browser I get a connection refused err.  I thought maybe it could be firewall related so I disabled that, but that didn't help.  I also tried going through the steps multiple times with different directory names, tried changing the port numbers and tried rebooting the machine.  I always get the same result.

At this point I think I've just run out of talent and can't think of anything else to try.  When I look at the package.json files they match what is shown on the page.  Hopefully I'm missing something obvious, I just can't see it.

Edit:

The code I've used is from the page....first one is:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
});

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8000!')
});
```

and the second spot I tried and got the listening message but couldn't connect  via a browser was after installing the express application generator and then running:

```
DEBUG=helloworld:* npm start
```

Edit 2:
If anyone else ever has this problem, I got it to work by following the instructions on this page instead.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/beginners#types-of-nodejs-applications  Now to figure out why...

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Nick and welcome to Stack Overflow!

What you did is probably installing the packages you had missing befor with `npm install`.

Or maybe you were not using the correct syntax to set that environment variable `DEBUG` on your machine.

If I can suggest, avoid using express-generator, it's much better to learn how to do that manually, it's just a couple of lines of code anyways!